# Markdown, Pandoc,LaTeX and admonitions

Tags: luatex, pandoc, markdown

I'm writing manuals for our programs using `Markdown` and serving with `MKDocs`, but I would also like to offer the manuals as a downloadable PDFs. Pandoc and the [Eisvogel](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) template go a long way, but as far as I can tell, one thing is missing; the [admonitions](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/admonitions/).

[The code from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347059/295507) look like the best solution *but how do I use it*?

If possible, I would like it to have as little impact on the Markdown files as possible, ideal is to add the whole thing to a separate file and use -H with Pandoc and everything magically works.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,marvosym,xstring}
\newcommand\boxcolor{}
\newcommand\mybox[3]{%
\IfStrEq{#1}{note}{\renewcommand\boxcolor{CornflowerBlue}}{%
   \IfStrEq{#1}{danger}{\renewcommand\boxcolor{Tomato}}{%
   \IfStrEq{#1}{warning}{\renewcommand\boxcolor{Crimson}}{}}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=\boxcolor!15!white,          
                  colframe=\boxcolor,
                  title=\sffamily\bfseries\Info\quad #2]
                  \sffamily #3
\end{tcolorbox}}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function triplebang (s)
  if not (boxedflag) then
    if string.find ( s , '^!!!' ) then
      boxedflag=true
      return string.gsub ( s, '^!!! (%a*) "(.*)"$', '\\mybox{%1}{%2}{' )
    else
      return s
    end
  else
    if string.find (s , '^XXX' ) then 
      return string.sub ( s , 4 )
    else
      boxedflag=false
      return '}' .. s
    end
  end
end
\end{luacode}

\def\startlooking{\directlua{%
   boxedflag=false
   luatexbase.add_to_callback(
      'process_input_buffer', triplebang , 'triplebang' )}}
\def\stoplooking{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
      'process_input_buffer' , 'triplebang' )}}

\begin{document}
\startlooking
Not part of the note.
!!! note "A Note Title"
XXXThis is
XXXa note with
XXXmultiple lines
XXX
XXXpossibly containing
XXXparagraph breaks.
Not part of the note either.
!!! danger "A Danger Title"
XXXThis is
XXXanother note with
XXXmultiple lines.
Further non-note text.
!!! warning "A Warning Title"
XXXThis is yet
XXXanother note with
XXXmultiple lines.
Still more non-note text.
\stoplooking
\end{document}
```

P.S. I would have commented on the answer above but (1) it's six years old and (2) I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: `Eisvogel` has [examples using admonitions](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/master/examples/boxes-with-pandoc-latex-environment-and-tcolorbox/document.md) with `pandoc-latex-environment` why don't you just use those?

Comment: @DG' Thanks but as far as I can tell, `MKDocs` (with material theme) doesn't support the colon designation, only exclamation marks.